# Absolute and relative dates displayed in OS language in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, localization

Dates for posts and comments are displayed in OS language in Android app instead of site (or the app) language.

> [image]

This looks weird on sites where main language is different from the OS language.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LM-G710
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (1831822582e60.FGN)

Comment: This seems more like a limitation with programming the app, and could be by design.

Comment: [The app uses some 3rd-party libraries packaged with localization support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224635/241919)...